# Select correct variable php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html-table, alert

I have a wishlist I built. It functions correctly with adding/displaying/remove items, but I want to take it further. When I delete an item, I want it to have a pop-up that says something like "Item X has been removed."

It's built inside an HTML `table` that generates the variable from a `foreach`.

**My Problem**: After it successfully deletes any item, the JS prompt will only grab the value of the first listed item.

I.E. If I click delete for any item, it will echo the variable from the first item everytime.
It does however delete the correct everytime.

**HTML**

```
`echo '<tr >
                    <td >
                        '.$shirt_name.'
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        '.$model_number.'
                    </td> 
                    <td style="padding-left:9px;"><div style="height:50px;background-size:contain;" class="'.$shirt_image.'">
                       </div>
                    </td>

        ';              
         ?>
              <? echo '<td>  
              <form action="delete_button.php" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" id="deleteitem" class="testbtn" name="deleteitem" value="'.$delete_shirt. '">
              <input type="submit" id="del_but" value="Remove" class="deleteBtn">
              </form></td>                 
              ';
```

**Javascript** *For brevity's sake here I'm only trying to echo the value of the input with*
     `class="testbtn"`

```
  <script>
$('.deleteBtn').click(function() {    
var deleteitem = $(".testbtn").val();
alert (deleteitem);
});
</script>`
```

So, it's only prompting the the value of the first listed `<tr>` instead of the relative one that I click. How do I make it grab the relative value?? I hope I made this clear enough!

Comment: Try `$(this).closest("tr").remove();` in the click handler

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't make any difference. It still grabs the first value...

Comment: maybe var deleteitem = $(this).prev().val();

Comment: Are you sure you are closing the tr element?

Comment: Is the item getting deleted in the database and a page refresh occuring?

Comment: @IvanLazarevic this gives me 'undefined' in my prompt

Comment: @Orangepill yes the <tr> is closed, and yes the correct item is being deleted from the database.

Comment: This isn't a clientside problem show your php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
$('.deleteBtn').click(function() {  
var deleteitem = $(this).parent().find('.testbtn').val();
alert (deleteitem);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Could you please briefly explain what it's doing here?

Comment: $(this) selects the deletebtn element object that was clicked , parent() selects his td parent object , find finds the the element object with tesbtn as its class (in the td context last selected) , and val() gets the value of selected testbtn

Answer (score 2):

Is there a "delete button" form for each shirt in the list? If so, then you can add the alert() call to the submit button, like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="alert('Click!'); return true;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)`
$(this) is the currently clicked button object.  Try doing a console.log($(this)) to see what it has.  If you need to select its parent row id or something do `$(this).parent("tr").attr("ID")`

Hope this helps! *no pun intended

Comment: `$(this).parent('tr')` will only match something if the click handler is on the td you probably mean `$(this).parent('td').parent('tr')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a template to show how you should do this.

```
<script>
$('.deleteBtn').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
       // do ajax to delete on the server
       $(this).closest("tr").remove();

   }
});
</script>
```

To dissect this line `$(this).closest("tr").remove();`

`$(this)` inside of a handler will return the element that received the event

`.closest("tr")` will give you the first ancestor that matches the selector `tr`

`.remove()` will remove the dom node.

Comment: Thank you but this isn't what I wasn't looking for at all. And if I click on 'Cancel' on the prompt, it still delete's the item from the db.

Comment: Yeah... I got that... you aren't doing ajax which is what this was geared for. Since you are doing a traditional post the page is just being re-rendered with the deleted item missing. JS has nothing to do with this one... so some more testing.

Comment: I'm going to have to use AJAX down the line anyway because I want the div to reload showing the new table without a page a refresh. But for now I'm taking it one step at a time. I might need help with that too, so keep an eye out in the near future! Thanks again ;-)

Comment: @user2118228 regardless... there is something buggy in your delete query, the javascript in all of these cases is running before the post  occurs and the record is deleted so all of the solutions on this page have no impact on the behavior you are seeing. The record being missing from the result set is a byproduct a clean page load with the result set having one less record in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Look at my code and look at the other two items and try and stick them together.

You really need to refactor this code, why would you have the button wrapped wrong a form when your doing a click event using javascript. if you do something like this it would be better:

```
<?php
    echo "<tr>
        <td>
            $shirt_name
        </td>
        <td>
            $model_number
        </td> 
        <td style=\"padding-left:9px;\">
            <div style=\"height:50px;background-size:contain;\" class=\"$shirt_image\"></div>
        </td>
        <td class=\"testbtn\" id=\"$model_id\">
            Delete
        </td>";              
?>

 <script>
$('.deleteBtn').click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id');

// DO SOME AJAX AND PUT THE ALERT IN THE SUCCESS

alert ('Deleted' + id);
});
</script>
```